# Use of single process to get output from 2 pipes

Tags: c, sockets, pipe

I need to implement like " who | sort | array". Output of sort should be saved in an array. I am able to do that successfully  using 2 pipes and forking twice. Is it possible that we can achieve the same without forking twice? Instead like use 2 pipe and single process.

Current logic:

```
child:

1) fork
      close(pipe(0))
      dup2(pipe(1),1)
      execlp ;
2) fork
      dup2(pipe(0),0)
      dup2(pipe(3),1)
      execlp ;
parent:
      dup2(pipe(2),0)
      and logic to save the same in an array
```

Comment: I may not understand exactly what you mean by "single process". Do you mean you still want to call `fork()`? To execute two different programs, you still have to fork twice, but you can wait for one to finish before you fork the other. Is that what you want to do?

Comment: Yes, i want to use fork once..

Comment: You still have to fork twice if you want to execute two programs. You can wait for one to finish before you fork the other. Is that what you want to do?

Comment: you should better explain what do you mean for " who | sort | array"

Comment: Never mind. I need to use 2 fork anyhow.. I have another problem. I defined double pointer and assignning memory to it dynamically. Now when i pressed ctrl+c it gives me eror like ^C*** glibc detected *** ./rsrtd: free(): invalid pointer: 0x007c63d0 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/libc.so.6[0x6a8041]
./rsrtd[0x8048f77]
./rsrtd[0x8048ff5]
[0xd4b400]
/lib/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xe6)[0x64fcc6]
./rsrtd[0x8048851]
======= Memory map: ========
00324000-00341000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 1194704    /lib/libgcc_s-4.4.5-20110214.so.1..  I even called inthandler to free memory but it doesnot work

Comment: void freememory(char **str)
{
   char **sr=str

  while(*sr)
 free(*sr++);

  free(str); 
  printf("Memory is free now");
}

void inthandler(int signum)
{ freememory(str);
  fclose(sfp);
  fclose(sfd);
}

Comment: Hi Guys thanks i have solved the issue. I think i need to slap myself tight.. I am making very silly mistakes...